# How to get categories and sub-categories in single API response

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, rest, express

I have two collections `Categories` and `Subcategories` inside a `Categories` collection. I have an array that is storing the ids of subcategories that are stored in `Subcategories` collection. Below is my document structure:

**Categories collection**

```
{
  id:65,
  title:"Automotive",
  active:true,
  subcategories:[35,28,30]
}
```

**subcategories collection**

```
{
  id:35,
  title:"Automotive technology",
  category_id:65,
  active:true
},
{
  id:28,
  title:"Automotive coatings",
  category_id:65,
  active:true
},
{
  id:30,
  title:"Machinery and equipments",
  category_id:65,
  active:true
}
```

As seen in above collection 3 documents from subcategories collection have been associated with the category document. I want to fetch data in below format on single API hit.

API response should be in below format:

```
{
 data:{
     category:{
               id:65,
               title:"Automotive",
               subcategories:[{
                                id:35, 
                                name:"Automotive technology",
                              },
                              {
                                id:28, 
                                name:"Automotive coatings",
                              },
                              {
                                id:30, 
                                name:"Machinery and equipments",
                             }]
              },
     category:{
                 id:66,
                 title:"Food",
                 subcategories:[{
                                 id:23, 
                                 name:"Drinks",
                                },
                                {
                                 id:2, 
                                 name:"Additives",
                               }]
               },
   },
   messsage:"Success",
   code:200
}
```

As of now I am able to get data in 2 api hits that is like first getting all the categories

```
 const category = await db.categories.find({});
```

Then on click of some particular category fetching all the sub categories based on the category id.

```
const subCategories = await db.SubCategories.find({category_id:id});
```

How can I get the above data in desired format in single API hit?

Comment: Have you tried using populate method?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-populate-method/

Also can you post your category and sub category schema?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DwnJUojC5va), also, if you use mongoose, you can use [.populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

To format data you can use [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage in aggregation pipeline or [projection in .find()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Mongoose with populate:

CategorySchema:

```
const CategorySchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  subCategories: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SubCategory' }],
  ...
});
```

- **need _id column on reference table**
- **ref content is must be equal to model name like**

  ```
  module.exports = mongoose.model('SubCategory', SubCategorySchema);
  ```

Controller:

```
const categories = await Category.find({})
  .populate({
    path: 'subCategories'
  })
```

- **path content is must be equal to column name**

If you want to write with Mongo query:

```
db.getCollection("categories").aggregate([
    {
       $lookup:
         {
             from: 'subCategories',
             localField: 'subCategories',
             foreignField: 'id',
             as: 'subCategories'
         }
    }
])
```

You get empty object because you are not using "_id" field for join schemas. If you want to use "id" field u need to use virtuals on Mongoose:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html#populate

Comment: I am trying populate method but its sending empty object.

Comment: Please refrain from "wanna" and "u" here - Stack Overflow is not a chatroom, and technical writing is preferred.